# Removing rows based on column conditions

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

Suppose we have a data frame:

```
Event <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C" , "C", "C")
Model <- c( 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)

df <- data.frame(Event, Model)
```

Which looks like this:

| event | Model |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |

We can see that event B only has 2 models of data. As the actual data frame I am using has thousands of rows and 17 columns, how can I remove all events that do not have 3 models? My guess is to use a subset however I am not sure how to do it when we have more than one condition.

I tried the suggested code from YH Jang below:

```
df %>% group_by(Event) %>% 
  filter(max(Model)==3)
```

However, this would miss out entries in the data that looked like this.

| event | Model |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 3 |

example:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   Event [2]
  Event Model
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 A         3
4 C         1
5 C         2
6 C         3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Event) %>% 
  filter(length(Model) >= 3)
```

or, more concisely:

```
 df %>% group_by(Event) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 3)
```

This removes rows that have fewer than three `Model` types

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`,

```
df %>% group_by(Event) %>% 
  filter(max(Model)=3)
```

the result would be

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   Event [2]
  Event Model
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 A         2
3 A         3
4 C         1
5 C         2
6 C         3
```

or using `data.table`,

```
df[df[,.I[max(Model)==3],by=Event]$V1]
```

the result is same as below.

```
   Event Model
1:     A     1
2:     A     2
3:     A     3
4:     C     1
5:     C     2
6:     C     3
```

**EDIT**
I misunderstood the question.
Here's the edited answer.

```
# with dplyr
df %>% group_by(Event) %>% 
  filter(length(Model)>=3)
```

or

```
# with data.table
df[df[,.I[length(Model)>=3],by=Event]$V1]
```

Comment: Superb thank you

Comment: While I thought that this code initially worked, it sometimes misses out models that are less than 3

Comment: @T.Omalley Could you give me an example which doesn't work?

Comment: Sure.. for instance when an event A has only models 1 and 3 available. as the max of 3 is still there it doesn't filter out the event.

Comment: @T.Omalley I think I misunderstood your question. You mean you want to remove events that have less than 3 models, not 'models 3'?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @T.Omalley No, it was my mistake. I just edited the answer.